# problem using cache

Tags: java, exception

I used the cache since 2 months in my project and it works properly, now I am trying to run the application but this exception occur for each line used the cache object

> warning: `sun.security.util.Cache` is Sun proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

What does that mean?

Comment: This is not the exception that is causing your implementation to fail. Please look further there should be an another problem. ( or if the run time environment has changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means exactly what it says - you shouldn't be using `sun.*` packages, basically.

I suggest you find an open source cache library. For example, [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`MapMaker`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release08/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) class can be used to create expiring caches.

Comment: Since it's just warning, why the system is not running?

Comment: @Alaa: I don't know - you haven't given nearly enough information as to what you mean by "not running". What sort of exception is being thrown? Is it really throwing an exception, rather than these being compile-time warnings?

Comment: @Alaa: In which case it's not an exception, and isn't going to stop your application working... yet. But take heed of the warning anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It means you are depending on a class that is not part of core java. It is something that Sun (The company that maintains java) has written. There is absolutely no guarantee that this class in the future will be available because Sun may sell or do something else.

If you want a better solution then you should depend on a more stable caching library. I recommend [ehcache](http://ehcache.org/).

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning. The manufacturer is telling you the code you're using will be removed at some point in the future.